# How can I see all the orders down my orders tab on onclick my orders

Tags: magento2, dashboard

[image: Dashboard]

I am trying to get my order list down below my orders tab on clicking my orders. how can I get that??

[image]

Comment: Can you mock up a screenshot on how you want it to look?

Comment: I have updated it. Please check it.